# What if an ocean planet is covered by superfluid ocean?

Tags: condensed-matter, planets, superfluidity

It is possible that an ocean planet can be covered by superfluid state liquid. What will happens on this kind of planet? Will there be any changes to tide? Will there be strong magnetic field? Will the superfluid evaporate away soon? Will there be big ocean mountain formed by solitary wave?

Actually, what I want to ask is, will there be some special or strange or beautiful or marvellous phenomena that wouldn't happen in earth?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question might be more suitable on [Worldbuilding SE](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions), although it is very broad even for Worldbuilding SE IMO.